# How to call web resource (html) function from other web resource(html)?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dynamics-crm-2011

I am using Dynamics CRM, in which we have two different web resources on same form. Now, when I tried to call java script function from one web resource to another, it gives following error.

```
Message: Object expected
Line: 10
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://dynamicscrm01/CRM01/%7B635481860480000809%7D/WebResources/new_htmlWithBorder
```

I am trying to call `toggle1()` function.

Callee Web Resource code:

```
  <title>T</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>

    <script>
        var x = 0;
    function  toggle1() {
        if (x) {
                    $("#sidebar").animate({
                        width: '10%'
                    }).hide()
                    $("#map").animate({
                        width: '89%'
                    });

                    x = 0;

                } else {
                    $("#sidebar").animate({
                        width: '89%'
                    }).show()
                    $("#map").animate({
                        width: '10%'
                    });

                    x = 1;
        }

            }

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

<div id="map"> 
  <input type="button" data-name="show"  onclick="toggle1();" value="Toggle" id="toggle">
</div>
<div id="sidebar">SIDEBAR</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Caller Web Resource:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<BODY>
<INPUT onclick=toggle1() value=Toggle type=button> 
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable in the window object and call it from other webresource

webresource_1.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="values" />
<script type="text/javascript">

    var mainFunction = function() {
        alert($("#values").val());
    }

    window.top.html1Function = mainFunction;

</script>
</body>
```

webresource_2.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="button"> </button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        var b = $("#button");

        b.click(function() { window.top.html1Function(); });

    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```